# Modifying number of arguments for callback functions - javascript

Tags: javascript

I know many of you already used JavaScript UI widget plugins, etc... that offers callback functions. For instance we have `Object x` and it has a function, let say `.doThisAfterAnEvent()`. And according to the official documentation of `Object x`, that function accepts a single parameter of type `function()` with one argument, let say `_args`.

To visualize, here is the example:

```
var handler = function(_args) {
    // Do something.
}

var x = $("#element-to-widget-ify").transform()
x.doThisAfterAnEvent(handler)
```

My question is, how can I modify the method `.doThisAfterAnEvent()` to accept a function *with two or more parameters* instead of one? In this case, I need to pass a second extra value to the `handler` function.

---

**Edit:**

```
var widgets = {
    "widget-at-the-nav": $("#nav-widget").transform(),
    "widget-at-the-footer": $("#nav-footer").transform(),
    "widget-at-the-search": $("#nav-search").transform(),
    length: 3
}

var handler = function(_args, _option) {
    console.log("key in: " + _option
    // Other processes...
}

for(key in widgets) {
    console.log("key outer: " + key)
    widget[key].doThisAfterAnEvent(function(json) {
        console.log("key out: " + key)
        handler(json, key)
    })
}
```

This is my attempt. But it prints like this:

```
key outer: widget-at-the-nav
key outer: widget-at-the-footer
key outer: widget-at-the-search
key out: widget-at-the-nav
key in: widget-at-the-nav
key out: widget-at-the-nav
key in: widget-at-the-nav
key out: widget-at-the-nav
key in: widget-at-the-nav
```

And I forgot to tell you guys that the function `.doThisAfterAnEvent()` (not the `handler()` function) has an `AJAX` call inside.

Comment: Why do you need a second parameter? Can you not just use an object such as `{param1: value1, param2: value2}`  as the sole parameter?

Comment: You need to change this in doThisAfterAnEvent, where the function call the callback. Can you post a content equivalent of doThisAfterAnEvent ?

Comment: @RayToal The function `.doThisAfterAnEvent()` creates an `Object` to be passed to the handler internally and I cannot modify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a mess, so I'm only going to touch on the most recent edit, and the code it contains.

Your approach with masking the handler with an anonymous function is pretty much correct, it's just that your loop is messing up your lexical scope.  The AJAX bit is a very important detail, because any AJAX calls are most likely going to operate long after you've looped, which means those callback functions will all reference the same final value of `key`.

You need to create a new scope where the key is 'locked in', so that the references are correct.

```js
function Con () {}

Con.prototype.doThisAfterAnEvent = function (fn) {
  // Fake some AJAX programming
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    fn.call(this);
  }, 1500);
  
};

$.fn.transform = function () {
  return new Con();
};

var widgets = {
  "widget-at-the-nav": $("#nav-widget").transform(),
  "widget-at-the-footer": $("#nav-footer").transform(),
  "widget-at-the-search": $("#nav-search").transform()
};

var handler = function(_args, _option) {
  console.log("key in: " + _option);
  // Other processes...
};

for (var key in widgets) {
  console.log("key outer: " + key);
  (function (key) {
    // Use an IIFE to establish a new lexical scope
    widgets[key].doThisAfterAnEvent(function(json) {
      console.log("key out: " + key);
      handler(json, key);
    });
  }(key));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In `ES6`, we'd use `let`.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask that, I guess you mean at the moment you call doThisAfterAnEvent, you already know one parameter over two for your handler.

In this case, the solution is too wrap your handler with two parameter in a anonymous function that only take one parameter and then call back your handler :

```
x.doThisAfterAnEvent(function(_arg) { handler(myKnownArg, _arg) });
```

Comment: Or you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context (`this`)

Comment: That write, that you can also use bind to prepend arguments to the function.